# Select a tableadapter at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, tableadapter

Suppose there are n buttons and one datagridview.

I drag a dataset which contains n tables, therefore create n tableadapters that has the same connection string. I want to click each button to display each table in each tableadapter respectively.

I think it is a bad idea.

Should I create tableadapter programmatically rather than drag a control to the form?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote for someone else this code:

```
//class variable:
DataSet ds  = new DataSet();

//fill dataset in some of your method:
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connString"))
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable("People");
    DataTable table2 = new DataTable("Cars");
    ds.Tables.Add(table1);
    ds.Tables.Add(table2);
    string query1 = @"SELECT * FROM People";
    string query2 = @"SELECT * FROM Cars";
    string[] queries = { query1, query2 };
    for(int i = 0; i < queries.Length; i++)
    {
         using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(queries[i], conn))
             da.Fill(ds.Tables[i]);
    }
}

//now bind tables to your button click events (this is example for Cars):
void button1_Click()
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Cars"].DefaultView; 

    //do the same for table "People" in some other button click event
}
```